# Split jinja string in airflow

Tags: jinja2, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I trigger my dag with the API from a lambda function with a trigger on a file upload. I get the file path from the lambda context
i.e. : `ingestion.archive.dev/yolo/PMS_2_DXBTD_RTBD_2021032800000020210328000000SD_20210329052822.XML`

I put this variable in the API call to get it back as `"{{ dag_run.conf['file_path'] }}"`

At some point, I need to extract information from this string by splitting it by `/` so inside the DAG to use the `S3CopyObjectOperator`.

So here the first approach I had

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.s3_copy_object import S3CopyObjectOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
}

s3_final_destination = {
    "bucket_name": "ingestion.archive.dev",
    "verification_failed": "validation_failed",
    "processing_failed": "processing_failed",
    "processing_success": "processing_success"
}


def print_var(file_path,
              file_split,
              source_bucket,
              source_path,
              file_name):
    data = {
        "file_path": file_path,
        "file_split": file_split,
        "source_bucket": source_bucket,
        "source_path": source_path,
        "file_name": file_name
    }

    print(data)


with DAG(
        f"test_s3_transfer",
        default_args=default_args,
        description='Test',
        schedule_interval=None,
        start_date=datetime(2021, 4, 24),
        tags=['ingestion', "test", "context"],

) as dag:
    # {"file_path": "ingestion.archive.dev/yolo/PMS_2_DXBTD_RTBD_2021032800000020210328000000SD_20210329052822.XML"}
    file_path = "{{ dag_run.conf['file_path'] }}"
    file_split = file_path.split('/')
    source_bucket = file_split[0]
    source_path = "/".join(file_split[1:])
    file_name = file_split[-1]

    test_var = PythonOperator(
        task_id="test_var",
        python_callable=print_var,
        op_kwargs={
            "file_path": file_path,
            "file_split": file_split,
            "source_bucket": source_bucket,
            "source_path": source_path,
            "file_name": file_name
        }
    )

    file_verification_fail_to_s3 = S3CopyObjectOperator(
        task_id="file_verification_fail_to_s3",
        source_bucket_key=source_bucket,
        source_bucket_name=source_path,
        dest_bucket_key=s3_final_destination["bucket_name"],
        dest_bucket_name=f'{s3_final_destination["verification_failed"]}/{file_name}'
    )

    test_var >> file_verification_fail_to_s3
```

I use the `PythonOperator` to check the value I got to debug.

I have the right value in `file_path` but I got in `file_split` -> `['ingestion.archive.dev/yolo/PMS_2_DXBTD_RTBD_2021032800000020210328000000SD_20210329052822.XML']`

It's my str in a list and not each part splited like `["ingestion.archive.dev", "yolo", "PMS_2_DXBTD_RTBD_2021032800000020210328000000SD_20210329052822.XML"]`.

So what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

In Airflow the Jinja rendering is not done until task runtime, however, since the parsing of the `file_path` value as written is performed as top-level code (i.e. outside of an Operator's `execute()` method or `DAG` instantiation, the file_path value is initialized as `[" {{ dag_run.conf['file_path'] }}"]` by the Scheduler.  Then when the task is executed, the Jinja rendering begins which is why you see `["ingestion.archive.dev/yolo/PMS_2_DXBTD_RTBD_2021032800000020210328000000SD_20210329052822.XML"]` as the value because there is no "/" in the initialized string.

Even if you explicitly split the string within the Jinja expression like `file_split="{{ dag_run.conf.file_path.split('/') }}"` the value will then be the string representation of the list and not a `list` object.

However, in Airflow 2.1, you can set `render_template_as_native_obj=True` as a DAG parameter which will render templated values to a native Python object. Now the string split will render as a `list` as you expect:
[image]

As best practice, you should avoid top-level code since it's executed every Scheduler heartbeat which could lead to some performance issues in your DAG and environment.  I would suggest passing the `"{{ dag_run.conf['file_path'] }}"` expression as an argument to the function which needs it and *then* execute the parsing logic within the function itself.